# What is the purpose of canberra-gtk-module?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, gtk

I see a lot of questions regarding the `"Failed to load canberra-gtk-module"` and got curious on what the purpose of this module actually is. Since the google searches only points to questions on how to fix it, I was hoping someone here knew the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the package description](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libcanberra-gtk-module) of `libcanberra-gtk-module`:

> translates GTK+ widgets signals to event sounds

[GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/) is a toolkit for creating GUIs, most of the default Ubuntu desktop, and the GNOME desktop environment, is developed using it. [`libcanberra`](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libcanberra/gtkdoc/libcanberra-canberra.html) is a library for playing sounds. `libcanberra-gtk-module`, then, is the module that takes GUI events from GTK+ (like pressing a button, or minimizing a window) and plays some configured sound.

The error message commonly seen maybe a result of these bugs:

- [#872172 - libcanberra-gtk0 should recommend Gtk2 and Gtk3 module to fix: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcanberra/+bug/872172)
- [#888779 - Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-moduleanberra-gtk-module" (sic)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcanberra/+bug/888779)
- [#689434 - Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcanberra/+bug/689434)